# How to fix "Failed to resolve (?wrong URL) cgminer.exe --bmsc-options"

Tags: cgminer, stratum

I downloaded CGMiner and have my pool with slushs pool. So below I believe is the correct setup for CGMiner.

```
cgminer.exe --bmsc-options 115200:20 -o stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u Starfleet.worker3 -p ***** --bmsc-freq 0781
```

However, every time I try and connect, it says exactly this:....

```
Failed to resolve (?wrong URL) cgminer.exe --bmsc-options
Pool 0 slow/down or URL or credentials invalid
Pool setup failed
```

Can anyone please help me, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. And I do not really know how to write script.

Answer (score 1):

Had you read the page on Slush's Pool on how to set up CGMiner, you would have gotten it right the first time. Use this:

```
cgminer.exe --bmsc-options 115200:20 -o stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -u Starfleet.worker3 -p * --bmsc-freq 0781
```